# SharePoint 201 Site Showing 3000+ Workflows "In Progress"

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

I inherited a SharePoint 2010 site and we have (all of a sudden) started having issues with our Approval workflow. It just seems to have stopped working. This site has been up for a couple of years, was upgraded from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 in the third quarter of last year and has been working since. Then yesterday the Approval process just stopped working. You can walk through it but it doesn't do a thing. The pages don't get published and the status of the page doesn't change from "In Progress".

In attempting to diagnose the issue I found that the workflow status page (/_layouts/wrkmng.aspx) is showing 3079 Approval workflows "In Progress"

[image]

Now I am no SharePoint expert by any stretch of the imagination but this does not seem right to me.

Is this correct? Could this be the issue I am having? Could there be some limit or cache that is filling up? How do I clear these things?